# List(1)#contains() returns `false`

Tags: scala

Given the following:

```
scala> List(1).contains()
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
res18: Boolean = false
```

Why does `false` return?

[List#contains](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) has the signature:

`def contains[A1 >: A](elem: A1): Boolean`

So, as I understand, `contains` argument must be equal or above `A`'s type.

Why does this return `false`?

Comment: `(): Unit` is the argument it gets from your `contains()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you run it again with `-deprecation` (as suggested by the warning), you'll see this:

```
scala> List(1).contains()
<console>:8: warning: Adaptation of argument list by inserting ()
  has been deprecated: this is unlikely to be what you want.
        signature: LinearSeqOptimized.contains[A1 >: A](elem: A1): Boolean
  given arguments: <none>
 after adaptation: LinearSeqOptimized.contains((): Unit)
              List(1).contains()
                              ^
res0: Boolean = false
```

So `List(1).contains()` is being parsed as `List(1).contains(())`, and the inferred type for `A1` is `AnyVal`, which is the least upper bound of `Unit` and `Int`.

The short answer: don't do this, it's bad. Slightly longer: don't do this, it's bad, and if the compiler suggests re-running with `-deprecation`, take it up on the offer—it'll probably make what's going on a little clearer.

Comment: Why isn't the `lub` resolved to `AnyVal`, rather than `Any`? `scala> lub(List(typeOf[Int], typeOf[Unit]))
res28: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = AnyVal`

Comment: @KevinMeredith Oh, you're probably right about `AnyVal`. It doesn't make any difference, though, since that type isn't used anywhere (`contains` effectively takes an `Any`, which is one of several issues that makes it almost worthless).